# late binding while option strict is on

Tags: vb.net

```
 Private Sub dgrKostendrager_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridItemEventArgs) Handles dgrKostendrager.ItemDataBound
    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem OrElse e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Then
        Dim btnTemp As Button = CType(e.Item.FindControl("btnSelecteer"), Button)
        btnTemp.Attributes.Add("onclick", "doSelect('" & e.Item.DataItem("KOSTL") & "','" & Replace(e.Item.DataItem("KLTXT"), "'", "\'") & "'); return false;")
    End If
End Sub
```

late binding issue at  `e.Item.DataItem("KOSTL")`   and `e.Item.DataItem("KLTXT")`

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Having `Option Strict On` is all about strict typing so you basically need to make sure that whatever type is expected is the type that you provide.  If a `String` is expected then provide a `String`.  That means either casting or converting what you have to that type.  For instance, if that `DataItem` member is type `Object` because it can return any type of object but it actually contains a `String` then cast as type `String` using `CStr`.

Comment: You should also look into using the `String.Format` method or, in later versions, string interpolation to make concatenating multiple values with literals easier to read and thus less error prone.

Comment: error is "option strict on disallow late binding"

Comment: Dim dataitem = DirectCast(e.Item.DataItem, something)

Answer (score 0):

> Error is for data type mismatch
>
> change e.Item.DataItem("KOSTL") to e.Item.DataItem("KOSTL").ToString()

```
Private Sub dgrKostendrager_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridItemEventArgs) Handles dgrKostendrager.ItemDataBound
    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem OrElse e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Then
        Dim btnTemp As Button = CType(e.Item.FindControl("btnSelecteer"), Button)
        btnTemp.Attributes.Add("onclick", "doSelect('" & e.Item.DataItem("KOSTL").ToString() & "','" & Replace(e.Item.DataItem("KLTXT").ToString(), "'", "\'") & "'); return false;")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: same option strict on disallow late binding